# How to insert the current date for a empty column in MySQL using a trigger?

Tags: mysql, date, if-statement, triggers, insert

My table (Report_table) has the following columns:
ID, Title, Text, Date.

Through my application I enter the title and text.
The database will automatically set the ID when inserted, but then I also want to automatically insert the date for each report using a trigger.

I'm a bit confused. Here is my suggestion but this isn't working:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trRDate
BEFORE INSERT ON Report_table
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF (Date IS NULL or Date = '')  THEN
SET NEW.Date = CURDATE();
END IF;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

So basically if the Date column is empty (which it is), then the trigger should insert a date.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL a trigger cannot modify the table which called it, so your current approach won't work.  But as of MySQL 5.6.5, you can specify a dynamic default value for a `datetime` column.

You can alter the `Date` column in your `Report_table` table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Report_table CHANGE `Date` `Date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This means that if you don't specify a date during inserts to `Report_table` the current timestamp will be used as default.

Another equally helpful option would be to assign the default date from your application.